# Parse date in Ext Js with / as separator

Tags: javascript, date, extjs

i am trying to parse a date in Ext JS as follows :

```
var date = new Date();
date = Ext.Date.parse("2/9/16","n/j/Y");
```

It creates an instance of the Date but when it tries to parse it, it returns undefined. I dont know where I am going wrong. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Use `y` (a two digit representation of a year) instead of `Y` (a full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits):

```
Ext.Date.parse("2/9/16","n/j/y")
```

Comment: I need the 4 digits of the year.

Comment: You can use `Ext.Date.parse("2/9/16","n/j/y")` or `Ext.Date.parse("2/9/2016","n/j/Y")`.

Comment: thats exactly what im doing but it returns undefined. @CD

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var date = Ext.util.Format.date( new Date(), "n/j/Y" );

console.log( date );
```

Answer (score -1):

var Date = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'm/d/Y');

Comment: Try to provide link of reference from where this information can be verified and any more general solutions can be derived. Moreover you can explain why the code in question is not working.